# XUL textbox addEventListener

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul

I'm trying to detect when a user hits escape or enter when in a xul textbox (firefox extension). But the following code doesn't seem to work. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

```
const KEY_ENTER = 13;
const KEY_ESCAPE = 27;

function keyPressed(e) {
   switch (e.keyCode) {
       case KEY_ENTER:
           // do something
           break;
       case KEY_ESCAPE:
           // do something
           break;
   }
}

var textbox = document.getElementById("mytextbox");
textbox.addEventListener('keypress', keyPressed, true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you running this script before the textbox has been inserted in the document?  This example works fine for me:

```
<window xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
<script type="application/javascript"><![CDATA[
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const KEY_ENTER = 13;
  const KEY_ESCAPE = 27;

  function keyPressed(e) {
     switch (e.keyCode) {
         case KEY_ENTER:
             alert('enter');
             break;
         case KEY_ESCAPE:
             alert('escape');
             break;
         default:
             alert('default');
             break;
     }
  }

  var textbox = document.getElementById("mytextbox");
  textbox.addEventListener('keypress', keyPressed, true);
  alert('there');
}, false);
]]></script>
<textbox id="mytextbox" value="stuff"></textbox>
</window>
```

I'm also a little curious why you're passing `true` as the capturing argument when adding the listener.  Generally you want to do stuff in the bubbling phase when handling events, not the capturing phase (i.e. after listeners on more-specific descendants of the element where you're listening have been called).